# syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip, erb

I am trying to have an image uploader on my app using Paperclip, and my only problem is that I keep getting an Undefined Method error. 
I have it set up on github, https://github.com/BBaughn1/savagelysaving

My User Controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
    def create
      @user = User.create( user_params )
    end

    def destroy
        @user.image = nil
        @user.save
    end

    private

    # Use strong_parameters for attribute whitelisting
    # Be sure to update your create() and update() controller methods.

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:image)
    end
end
```

Then my Show.html.erb file:

```
    <div id="post_content">
  <h1 class="title">
    <%= @post.title %>
  </h1>

  <p class="date">
    Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %>
      | <%= link_to "Delete", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <% end %>
  </p>

  <p class="body">
    <%= @post.body %>
    <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:medium) %>
  </p>

  <div id="comments">
    <%= render 'disqus' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my post.rb file:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :body, presence: true

  attr_accessor :image

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100#" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

in my development.rb file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ***STUFF***

  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

end
and posts controller:

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
    attr_accessor :image
  end

  def create
    attr_accessor :image 
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    attr_accessor :image
    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body, :image))
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no **avatar** attribute in your user model but there is an **image** attribute in your post model.

If you remove below code from user model and move it to post model, the image upload will work

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

This should fix the bug.

Comment: So I did that and I got a weird error. I get a message saying "Post model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'" so I put that in there and it gave me this: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.' and I tried to google the problem but nothing is working

Comment: Did you run rake db:migrate? Update your code and push to the repo and let me know when its done, I will review whats wrong with it.

Comment: I still have the error after the "rake db:migrate" command. It is posted in github, and this is my create def: def create
    (at)post = Post.new(post_params)
    attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'
    if (at)post.save
      redirect_to (at)post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

Comment: Have you got it to work yet, I got the latest code from your master branch and I am able to run without any error.

Comment: No (sorry about being late to this post, I had school (in 11th grade) then work), but I'm trying though

Comment: Are you trying to attach image with Post or with User, what is the objective here?

Comment: With a post. It's a blog so I'm trying to accomplish choosing a photo, then posting it so I have it in my Post

Comment: The above code is updated for you, and it's also available on github

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89981/discussion-between-zahid-and-brendon-baughn).

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your github to see if you made the same mistake I did. I think you forgot to add imagemagick to your development.rb file. When you install imagemagick on your local machine, it need to see where it's installed; `which convert` where show where. It might look like this `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"` if not, just copy what it show you and edit what's in the quotes " ".

I hope that helps I know I was having some trouble getting it to work.

Comment: I did at the very start. Guess I shoulda mentioned it, sorry. I'll edit my question